# Acyclic Undirected Graph

Tags: graph-theory

Let $G=(V,E)$ be an undirected graph.

Prove or disprove: If $|E|\le |V| - 1$ then $G$ is acyclic.

I am unsure about if this is even true or not in the first place. I know that trees have $n-1$ edges, but I do not know if this quality can deem that $G$ is acyclic (a tree).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a triangle and add an isolated vertex, you have a graph with $|E|\leq |V|-1$ and a cycle.

If you add the hypothesis $G$ is connected however, then it is true.

Answer (score 1):

HINT: Trees are simply the connected acyclic undirected graphs. Thus, every component of an acyclic undirected graph is a tree. (Indeed, another name for acyclic undirected graphs is *forest*.) Now use what you know about trees to prove a formula relating the number of vertices of a forest to the number of edges and the number of components (trees).

Comment: Doesn't the fact that it is not specified that $G$ must be connected as @Gamamal stated below make this not true for ANY undirected graph $G$ though?

Comment: @Groupsn'Stuff: What I wrote is true as written, but it was probably too obscure a hint. Were you to pursue it to the end, you’d find that **Gamamal**’s graph does not satisfy the formula in question, and conversely, the formula would make it very easy to come up with counterexamples like that one. Since you have **Gamamal**’s answer available, I’ll delete this one; let me know when you’ve seen this comment.

Comment: So as the statement stands, @Gamamal is correct because the condition of being connected is not present, but if it were I would see that this statement is true?

Comment: Why do you say my graph does not satisfy the formula? $3\leq 4-1$

Comment: @Gamamal: I did not say that. I said that it does not satisfy the formula that my answer was designed to help the OP discover, the one relating the numbers of vertices, edges, and trees of a forest.

Comment: Oh I see, thanks for the answer.

Comment: @Groupsn'Stuff: Yes, to both questions.

Comment: I don't think you should delete your answer.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott thank you for the clarification

Comment: @Gamamal: Okay; with these comments it’s probably a lot more understandable!

Comment: @Groupsn'Stuff: You’re welcome.